# Django Upgrade: Static Files Not Served

Tags: python, css, django

I have upgraded to Django 1.10 from 1.9.6.  Below is my urls.py file which previously worked:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.static import serve
from dwad import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('meta.urls')),
    url(r'^straightred/', include('straightred.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]

# Get Django to serve media files in debug mode.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [url(r'^resources/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})]

if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^resources/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    ]
```

When try to run the site I get:

```
view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

I know the above error is due to the 'django.views.static.serve' being in strings.  If I remove them from strings and link to the actual view i get the following error:

```
name 'django' is not defined
```

If I delete everything from "Get Django to serve media files in debug mode." and below the site loads but no static or media files are served.  This obviously means no css is applied and no images are loaded.

If people can offer some advice on next steps that would be appreciated.

Some settings that may be useful:

```
# Static files
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/str8red.com/static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

MEDIA_URL = '/resources/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media' if DEBUG else '/var/www/str8red.com/resources/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind the error is that, Django 1.10 no longer allows you to specify views as a string (e.g. 'myapp.views.home') in your URL patterns.

Try this,

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

#If you are in production (means running using nginx, or apache),
# you don't need this setting. Because, the media and static files
# are served by the nginx/apache, instead of Django.
#if settings.DEBUG:
    #urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks for a swift response.  I got the following error with the above "name 'static' is not defined"

Comment: import static from django.conf.utils.urls, updated the code

Comment: Well, the good news is that the site loads but there is still no images or css being served.  Do you need to see any of my settings perhaps?

Comment: Post the settings.py for your static and media

Comment: Added some detail, let me know if that is enough :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144905/discussion-between-alan-tingey-and-fazil-zaid).